# Relation between bounded first derivative and behaviour of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let me begin with an example first:

Consider $\;f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R\;$ such that $\;f(x)=\tanh x\;$. Then its plot is given below:
[image]

Now, the first derivative of $\;f\;$ is equal to $\;f'(x)=\frac{2}{e^x + e^{-x}} \equiv \frac{1}{\cosh x} \;$ which is a bounded function. Its plot is also given below:

[image]

I observe that $\;f\;$ goes from the value $-1$ to the value $+1$ in a "smooth" ,kind of, way.(I'm sorry I lack of the best word to describe the behaviour of $\;f\;$)

I wonder if the above behaviour of $\;f\;$ is related to the fact that its first derivative is bounded.

1. **If my assumption is true, why does this hold?**
2. **If I had a function which first derivative wasn't bounded, then what could I claim about the behaviour of $\;f\;$ in this case?**

I'm searching for some examples but I can't find any...

I hope I made my question clear enough. Any help would be valuable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "assumptions" do you only mean that the derivative is bounded? Do you require the derivative to exist at every point?

Comment: @Pawel Yes, all  I have is the boundness of the derivative..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your function to be

$$
 f (x) =
  \begin{cases}
 0 & \text{if } x<0 \\
 x+1 & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\
  \end{cases}
$$

Then $f$ has a bounded derivative but it is not "smooth" because it is discontinuous at $0$.

If your derivative is not bounded, then you can't claim much about boundness of the original function. For example, $f=\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$ is a bounded function, but it's derivative is not bounded. However, $g(x)=e^x$ is a function that is not bounded and whose derivative is not bounded.

Answer (score -1):

If your 1st derivative is not bounded then either your function is not continuous from both side of domain or it is discontinuous
e.g.
consider these function
\begin{cases}
 \sqrt{x}, & \text{x ∈ [ 0 , 1 ]}\end{cases}
as it has derivative unbounded near zero hence it has not left hand side continuity
and,
\begin{cases}
 1 / x, & \text{x ∈ R}\end{cases}
but in this case the function is not continuous at x = 0
therefore unbounded discontinuity does tells us so much about continuity and much more stuff

Comment: The function $f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ on $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ extends to a continuous function on all of $\mathbb R$ but has an unbounded derivative.